# Angular 5: TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to write a custom password match validator and am getting a TypeError in the console when I type two different passwords. I am using Angular Material controls and using classes for the validation. I want to avoid ReactiveForms and FormGroup if possible. I have been trying several methods but cannot get the confirm password method to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

TypeScript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './password-reset.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./password-reset.component.css']
})
export class PasswordResetComponent {
    hide = true;
    imageSrc = '../../assets/images/logo.png';
    password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, 
     Validators.minLength(8)]);
    confirm_password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, 
    Validators.minLength(8)], this.passwordMatchValidator);


    passwordMatchValidator(FormControl) {
       return this.password.value !== this.confirm_password.value
       ? null : { 'mismatch': true };
    }
     getPasswordErrorMessage() {
       return this.password.hasError('required') ? 'Please enter a password' 
         :
        this.password.hasError('minlength') ? 'Password must be at least 8 
         characters' :

        '';
     }
   getConfirmPasswordErrorMessage() {
      return this.confirm_password.hasError('required') ? 'Please enter a 
      password' :
      this.confirm_password.hasError('minlength') ? 'Password must be at 
       least 8 characters' :
       this.confirm_password.hasError(this.passwordMatchValidator) ? 
      'Passwords must match' :

        '';
     }


  }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <mat-form-field class="justifier">
        <input matInput placeholder="Password" [formControl]="password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)">{{getPasswordErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
        <mat-icon class="pw mat-icon2" matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <mat-form-field class="justifier">
        <input matInput placeholder="Confirm Password" [formControl]="confirm_password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="confirm_password.invalid || password.value !== confirm_password.value || (confirm_password.dirty || confirm_password.touched)">{{getConfirmPasswordErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
        <!--<mat-error *ngIf=" password.value !== confirm_password.value">both passwords must match!</mat-error>-->

        <mat-icon class="pw mat-icon2" matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPM6t.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here implies an undefined 'this'. 
Try creating a bound version of the function.

```
this.passwordMatchValidator.bind(this)
```

The issue here is that the function is not immediately invoked, but rather as a callback when angular calls the validator, so the 'this' context is lost. .bind ensures this works as you would expect. For more info, please https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript